# Is there a way to use angular base href as variable in image path?

Tags: angular

Using the Angular template built into VS 2017.
I have an image in the assets/image folder, so ClientApp > src > assets > images.

I reference the image in my component like:

```html
<img src="../../../assets/images/Logo.png" />
```

When deployed local, it works but after deploying to IIS it results in 404 error.

On the server, the app is deployed to a subfolder:
inetsrv8/internal/MyApp

I have to change the BASE HREF before deploying to get the app to work, so I'm thinking a fix would be to build custom paths for the images along the lines of BaseHref + './pathToImage'. The problem is I can't figure out how to grab the BASE Href to put it in a variable.

Is there a better way? A proper way? If not, how would I get the base href?

Comment: `<img src="./assets/images/Logo.png" />`

Comment: Well heck, I thought I tried that.  Works like a charm. I guess I was trying to be too fancy.  Thanks. Add as answer.

Comment: added ;) .... Please mark as answer or give upvote if it is helpful

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this.

`<img src="./assets/images/Logo.png" />`

Actually it depends on build structure. Best way is to check `angular-cli` configuration. Otherwise `ng built` and check where is your assert files.

Comment: but you still need to have your app to be "developpable" so with this you just broke : ng serve

Comment: But this would not work, if I have not set base href for dev environment

Answer (score 10):

Had trouble in SCSS to reference image too.
Using ~ did the trick :

```
$menu-icon-calendar: url('~/assets/menu/icon/calendar.png');
```

Comment: This gives me Error: Can't resolve '/assets/icon.svg' in '/.../src/styles'

Answer (score 6):

You can add the `APP_BASE_HREF` injection token in the providers:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useFactory: (s: PlatformLocation) => s.getBaseHrefFromDOM(),
      deps: [PlatformLocation]
    }
  ],
```

then inject it in a service (or component)

```
export class UrlService {

  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private _baseHref: string
  ) { }

  baseHref(): string {
    return `/${strip(this._baseHref, '/')}`;
  }

  rootRelative(s: string): string {
    return `${rstrip(this.baseHref(), '/')}/${lstrip(s, '/')}`;
  }
}
```

Then in your template, you can use that function (if you've injected UrlService)

`<img [src]="urlService.rootRelative('/assets/images/blah.png') />`

Comment: what is strip,  I could not find that method could you figure that method

Comment: Oops - I forgot those were just helpers I have which work the same like python, essentially for trimming characters. Here it is just normalizing to support both including and not-including the leading slash as well as trailing slashes

Comment: Thank You for the snippet, I have used TypeScirpt methods for handling it.